# Is it impossible to call constructor if object is created with template?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I wrote some simple code while I was trying to understand pointer stuff in c++. And I found out that a constructor does not work.
I have no idea what is happening here.

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    T* Data;
    Node<T>* right;
    Node<T>* left;
};


class SimpleClass
{
    public:

    SimpleClass() 
    { 
        data = 0;
        std::cout << "\n\t Get Resources!\n"; 
    }
    SimpleClass(int _value)
        : data(_value)
    {}
    ~SimpleClass() { std::cout << "\n\t Return Resources! \n"; }
    void SetValue(int _value)
    {
        data = _value;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "\n\t Value : " << this->data << "\n";
    }
    private:
        int data;
};
```

And here is main function

```
int main(void) 
{
    Node<SimpleClass>* A = new Node<SimpleClass>[1];
    Node<SimpleClass>* temp = new Node<SimpleClass>[1];

    return 0;

}
```

I expect `A` and `temp` to call constructor each time but they don't. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you create an object for Class Node and not create any object of class SimpleClass so the constructor of this class is not called.

```
  int main(void) 
  {
       Node<SimpleClass>* A = new Node<SimpleClass>[1];
       Node<SimpleClass>* temp = new Node<SimpleClass>[1];
       A->Data = new SimpleClass();
       temp->Data = new SimpleClass(10);
       return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are creating 2 objects of type `Node<SimpleClass>` and the constructor for this class is called twice. You can verify with:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node() { std::cout << "Node constructor\n"; }
    T* Data;
    Node<T>* right;
    Node<T>* left;
};


class SimpleClass
{
    public:

    SimpleClass() 
    { 
        data = 0;
        std::cout << "\n\t Get Resources!\n"; 
    }
    SimpleClass(int _value)
        : data(_value)
    {}
    ~SimpleClass() { std::cout << "\n\t Return Resources! \n"; }
    void SetValue(int _value)
    {
        data = _value;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "\n\t Value : " << this->data << "\n";
    }
    private:
        int data;
};

int main(void) 
{
    Node<SimpleClass>* A = new Node<SimpleClass>[1];
    Node<SimpleClass>* temp = new Node<SimpleClass>[1];

    delete[] temp;
    delete[] A;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to call the constructor of `SimpleClass` you should create an object of this type, e.g. with:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node() { std::cout << "Node constructor\n"; }
    T* Data;
    Node<T>* right;
    Node<T>* left;
};


class SimpleClass
{
    public:

    SimpleClass() 
    { 
        data = 0;
        std::cout << "\n\t Get Resources!\n"; 
    }
    SimpleClass(int _value)
        : data(_value)
    {}
    ~SimpleClass() { std::cout << "\n\t Return Resources! \n"; }
    void SetValue(int _value)
    {
        data = _value;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "\n\t Value : " << this->data << "\n";
    }
    private:
        int data;
};

int main(void) 
{
    Node<SimpleClass>* A = new Node<SimpleClass>[1];
    Node<SimpleClass>* temp = new Node<SimpleClass>[1];

    A->Data = new SimpleClass;
    delete A->Data;

    delete[] temp;
    delete[] A;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Node` does not contain a `T` (or in this case a `SimpleClass`) - it contains a pointer to a `T`. So the `Node` is constructed and the pointers it contains is constructed, but the `T` (`SimpleClass`) is not.

You can change `T* Data;` to `T Data;` and you will see your `SimpleClass` be constructed, or give `Node` a constructor that creates a new `T`.

So something like:

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    T Data;
    Node<T>* right;
    Node<T>* left;
};

or

template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node() : Data{ new T() } {}
    T* Data;
    Node<T>* right;
    Node<T>* left;
};
```